# Drupal 6: Using Organic groups for Educational page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, customization, organic-groups

I am working on a departmental website within a big university and want to add different types of functionality for different users depending on their roles.

There are 3 main types of users:

- Publicly listed
- Alumni (listed but based on different fields and using a custom template file)
- Others (users on site but not listed)

Right now we are using **Content Profiles** for the publicly listed users and list the content in the core profile tables for the alumni.

**The problem is**: If I'm faculty I still see all the fields for alumni (although it is in its own tab) and if I am alumni I see all the fields for faculty.

**Question**: What I would like to do is provide them **different views** of editing "My Account" based on their roles. So I wonder, would it be possible to do this with organic groups or is this something that needs custom PHP coding?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about limiting fields, then it has nothing to do with OG.

I think you're looking for the [conditional fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

This way you can set a node as 'alumni' or 'faculty', and depending on it show different fields.

Comment: Thank for the response :) I'm trying out "conditional fields" right now. Not sure if this will work but I am trying it out right now. The question is if it can hide groups. Also what I noticed is that it actually hides field using JavaScript instead of simply not outputting the fields in the first place.

Not sure how good that is, seems cleaner when the fields and groups of fields are simply not outputted in the first place.

Comment: Actually it only helps me trigger a field down the line in one particular form based on what values where selected in a field above it. For instance, in a "Country" dropdown, if the user selects "Sweden" the rest of the form can reflect this by hiding elements/fields that are specific to the US, like state.
Thanks but this did not solve it.